# minimum marriage possible algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

There are some men M1, M2, .... Mn and some women are given W1, W2, W3, .....Wm. and there is one 2-d matrix also given, that tells about the interest of men to whom he likes.
Calculate number of marriages required to marry all of the men and women.

`constraint:` One man can marry with multiple women and one woman can marry with multiple man.

`Approach that I think:`  I think this problem can solve with bipartite, but I am confused what the cases used to start the problem. Kindly guide to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean "one man has multiple possible women to marry, but can marry only one of them", or do you really mean "one man can marry multiple women at once"?

Comment: one man can marry multiple women at once and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

You want the smallest edge cover, which is a polynomial-time problem.  You can use the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm to find a maximum matching and then draw an edge from each of the unconnected points to any of its possible mates.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover

Comment: (Man, my first answer to this question was INCREDIBLY wrong.)

Comment: I assume you mean [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)?  The problem is most definitely in [NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29), but that doesn't really tell you much.

Comment: Yeah, I did.  Surprisingly though, I went to my graph theory textbook and the correct solution is apparently much faster than that!

Comment: Your answer still is incomplete (and in its current state wrong).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I think I read ariza's answer in wrong way, I thought he means connect nodes in maximum bipartite matching (that was my wrong).